# Mongoose "Create" method - Is there no callback? (Using passport and angular)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongoose, passport-local, passport.js

I am using mongoose to create a user object on register. This works fine and any errors are returned as expected.

However, I want to log the user on right after they register (so registering logs you on if there are no errors).

I have the following for the register.

register_controller:

```
$scope.submitRegister = function() {
    AuthenticationService.register(this.details).success(function() {
        $log.debug('/POST to /api/register worked');
    });
}
```

services.js:

```
.service('AuthenticationService', function($http, $timeout, $q, $session, $flash) {
    ...
    this.register = function(details) {
        var register = $http.post('/api/register', details);
        register.success(function() {
            console.log("User added fine"); 
        }).error(function() {
            console.log("error!!!");
        });
        return register;
    };
    ...
```

users.js:

```
app.post('/api/register', authentication.register);
```

passport's authenticate.js:

```
module.exports = {
...
  register: function(req, res){
    var User = require('./controllers/api/login_api');
    User.create({name: req.body.name, email: req.body.email, password: req.body.password}, function(err){
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
      }
      console.log("User added"); 
      return res.send(200);
    });
  },
...
```

The error is reported back fine, no troubles, but I would have thought it would report something else back (like the created object?) which I could use down the line so my register_controller can have in the success `function(object) {... login(object);...}`.

Is this a limitation in the .create method or am I missing something obvious?

Thank you.

Comment: just btw, I'd return a 4XX response if some error happens you can catch them all using an interceptor on the client side.

Comment: You want to return the created object from mongo to your client?

Comment: @jack.the.ripper `if (err) {console.log(err); return res.send(4XX, err); }` - like that?

@BenDiamant that's correct, after the register, in the success callback I want to call login, which requires email & password to login (`login(credentials)`)

Comment: @Gary correct, it's a good practice to send always a response, you can handle on the client side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things to change in your server code:

passport's authenticate.js:

```
module.exports = {
...
  register: function(req, res){
    var User = require('./controllers/api/login_api');
    User.create({name: req.body.name, email: req.body.email, password: req.body.password}, function(err, user){
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
      }
      console.log("User added"); 
      return res.send(200, user);
    });
  },
...
```

I've added user to your callback [Mongoose model.create api](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create) - return the created object to the CB

And to change the catch in your client:

```
.service('AuthenticationService', function($http, $timeout, $q, $session, $flash) {
...
this.register = function(details) {
    var register = $http.post('/api/register', details);
    register.success(function(user) {
        console.log(user); 
    }).error(function() {
        console.log("error!!!");
    });
    return register;
};
...
```

Now you can do with the created user object whatever you need

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks. Didn't think to add it there!